# Django: Where does this zip file create to?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

For some context, I have a `django-rest-framework` project. This particular endpoint takes a json blob, and zips it before saving it to a FileField. My question is– where exactly is this zip file I'm creating saving to? Just the root directory? Will these regularly need to be cleaned up?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def create_zip(self, user, jsondata):
        filename = "data" + ".zip"
        with gzip.GzipFile(filename, "w") as fout:
            fout.write(jsondata.encode("utf-8"))

        my_model = MyModel.objects.create(
            user=user, animation_file=filename
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems that the zip file is created in the current directory of your project script. And that needs to be cleaned up.

A more clear way to do this is to use some temp directory. For e.g. you may create a setting `TEMP_ROOT` and prefix your file with the temp root path using `os` module i.e

```
from django.conf import settings

import os
file_path = os.path.join(settings.TEMP_ROOT, filename)
```

and use this file_path to be given to `gzip.GzipFile()` method instead of `filename`.

Please make sure that the temp directory exists already.